# Looping in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, loops, for-loop, plpgsql

I am new to PostgreSQL and have a simple task with a looping structure.

Trying to print 0 to 10. Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOOPING()
RETURNS TABLE(asd text) AS
$BODY$declare 
i integer;      
Begin       

i:=0;
WHILE i > 10  LOOP
  select  i;
  i:=(i+1);
END LOOP;

end;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION LOOPING()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I have tried with while loop. If anybody can do this task with for loop it will be very helpful.

Comment: Please do not change the nature of the question after answers have been given. Start a new question for a new question.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake ... please find new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650581/for-loops-with-string-in-postgresql

Comment: I rolled back for you - assuming you agree.

Comment: ya sure..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several hick-ups in there. One working way (of many):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_loop()
  RETURNS TABLE(asd int) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
asd := 0;

WHILE asd < 11 LOOP
   RETURN NEXT;
   asd  := asd + 1;
END LOOP;

END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_loop();
```

#### FOR loop

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_loop()
  RETURNS TABLE(asd int) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP
   asd := i;
   RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;

END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Or, for this simple case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_loop()
  RETURNS SETOF int AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 0..10 LOOP
   RETURN NEXT i;
END LOOP;

END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

[Details in the excellent manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)

Comment: Thank you very much.. can you show me how to do same thing with for loop... please.

Comment: what will be a difference when i am dealing with strings in for loops..?

Comment: @AijazChauhan: The loop variable `i` is an integer. You can cast to text. `RETURN NEXT i::text;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem as far as I can see is that you have to return the value properly and RETURN NEXT in my experiments (on Pg 9.1) did not work as I expected it to.

I tested this and it was working:

```
create or replace function loop() returns table (i int)
language plpgsql as
$$
declare i_array int[];
begin
    for i in 0 .. 10 loop
         i_array := i_array || i;
    end loop;
    return query select unnest(i_array);
end;
$$;
```

Comment: you do some really strange. RETURN NEXT works well from 7.4. This is not good advantage :)

Comment: Pavel, In looking at Erwin's code, I think the issue is that I usually don't do table returning functions and the problem may be scoping.  You can't just return next and have the loop variable returned it seems.

Comment: @ChrisTravers: One can't mix `RETURN NEXT i` with `RETURNS TABLE (...)` is all. I included another examples to demonstrate both viable routes.

Comment: Erwin, yeah, as I noted in your code you copied the variable before you returned it.  Hence the comment that this may be a scoping issue.  Without copying, you just get a set of 11 NULLs returned... I find that behavior counter-intuitive (which is why I usually use RETURNS SETOF() functions).