# For loops with string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql

Here I am trying to concatenate a string with `,`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION looping() RETURNS TABLE(round text)
DECLARE
  i RECORD;
BEGIN

FOR i IN select regexp_split_to_table('33,55,66,88', ',') as "asd"
LOOP
  str:= str || ',' ||(select  i."asd");
END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is it true or am I missing something?

Comment: what were you planning to do with 'str', you haven't declared or used it anywhere except in the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often, a set-based operation with standard SQL functions is superior to looping.
But if you need the control structure in plpgsql, would work like this (one of many ways):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_loop2(OUT str text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i text;
BEGIN
str := '';

FOR i IN
   SELECT regexp_split_to_table('33,55,66,88', ',')
LOOP
  str :=  str || ',' || i;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```